# Sharepoint server 2010 Central Administrationa and other settings

Tags: c++, sharepoint-2010, unmanaged

I want to read following setting configured on Sharepoint server 2010:

1. file types blocked" for web
   application
2. Anti-virus setting
   configured to scan documents on
   upload
3. Is error report collection
   enabled (Central Administration >
   Operations > Logging and Reporting >
   Error Reports > ) etc.

My question is, where are these setting stored on sharepoint server machine? Are they in any config file or in database?

I know programmatic way to read these settings (Got Sharepoint 2010 SDK sample code in C#), but my application is in C++ (VS 2003 .Net) and all the API/interfaces are available in .Net (managed code). Please let me know if the API/interfaces to access these setting are available in unmanaged code also?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Krishnakant

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call sharepoint API in unmanaged code.

The settings are stored in sharepoint configuration database and must be called as you say in the SDK. You will need to create a .NET class library assembly which you will need to call from your managed code as a COM DLL.

Comment: Thanks Madhur!! Can I access DB to read this setting i.e. can you please guide me to the table?

Comment: You should NOT access the sharepoint DB's directly, as this will put your environment in an unsupported state!

Comment: Thanks Colin!! I am looking into .Net introp to read the settings.